# Rolling file for ETW EventSource .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, logging, etw, etw-eventsource

I've been trying to work with ETW in .net 4.5.

I have a WCF Service and Console App, and I want which uses EventSource to write messages, however, I'm struggling to understand how to create my own ETW (EventSource and EventListener) for log to a file (rolling file).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [magicandre1981's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238777/797144), you should add: -

```
TraceEventSession _session  = new TraceEventSession(
    "yourSessionName", @"C:\yourLogFile.etl")
{ 
    CircularBufferMB = 100 //100mb rolling log file
};
_session.EnableProvider(TraceEventProviders.GetEventSourceGuidFromName(
    "Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog"), TraceEventLevel.Always);
```

This can be in the same application as you are logging from (in process), or in a completely separate application (out of process).

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Nuget Package of Microsoft EventSource Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2013/08/10/the-eventsource-nuget-package-and-support-for-the-windows-event-log-channel-support.aspx)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource -Pre
```

and define the Events in a class which is derived from EventSource.

[image: EventSourceDemo]

Now use the [Semantic Logging Application Block](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging) from `Enterprise Library` to consume Events.

Here is a video how to use it:

**Introducing Semantic Logging**

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Introducing-Semantic-Logging